# How do I use two runtime variables to get an index of the other?

Tags: windows, batch

I am trying to write a script to read user input to make selections for an IP manager but I am having issues formatting 1 variable to be an index of the other. I have tried a lot of different methods but nothing yet.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
cd %~dp0
set OPT=
set CLN=
if exist IPManCfg.cmd (
call IPManCfg.cmd
) else (
echo Active Network Adaptors:
set /a fc=1
for /F "skip=3 tokens=1,2,3* delims= " %%G in ('netsh interface show interface') DO (
set OPT[!fc!]=%%J
echo [!fc!] %%J
set /a fc+=1
)
set /P CLN="Please select the listed adaptor: "
echo you've selected !CLN! which is !!OPT[!CLN!]!!
endlocal
```

with an output:

> you've selected 2 which is CLN

Comment: Try replacing `!!` with `!`

Comment: that unfortunately tries to display a var called !OPT[! , a string of CLN and another var of !]!

Comment: I also tried ```set "selopt=OPT!CLN!"
call echo you've selected !CLN! which is !!selopt!!```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to add another loop `For /L` and a condition like this code :

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
cd %~dp0
set OPT=
set CLN=
echo Active Network Adaptors:
set /a fc=1
@for /F "skip=3 tokens=1,2,3* delims= " %%G in ('netsh interface show interface') DO (
    set OPT[!fc!]=%%J
    echo [!fc!] %%J
    set /a fc+=1
)

set /P CLN="Please select the listed adaptor: "
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%fc%) do (
    If "!CLN!" EQU "%%i" (
        echo you've selected !CLN! which is "!OPT[%%i]!"
    )
)
pause
endlocal
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully! the only tweak I made was to make sure the %fc% was a !fc! and it did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example for possible codings.
These codings can also be used for e.g. 'set' commands instead of 'echo' commands.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

REM --- prepare some data ---
set IDX=2
set "STRING[%IDX%]=my string"

REM --- possible codings for data output ---
     echo 1: !STRING[%IDX%]!
     echo 2: !!STRING[%IDX%]!!
call echo 3: !!STRING[%IDX%]!!
call echo 4: %%STRING[!IDX!]%%

REM this works also without 'enableextensions' and 'enabledelayedexpansion'
call echo 5: %%STRING[%IDX%]%%

exit /b 0
```